# Gulp stream errors using merge2 1.2.0

Tags: gulp

I've been struggling with this for a few hours now. I've started a new project and using Gulp 3.9.1 and merge2 1.2.0 my old build scripts are failing because gulp.src doesn't seem to return correct streams to merge. In the code example I'm also using gulp-debug and gulp-zip.

```
merge(
 gulp.src(['*.foo'], {base: '.'})
 .pipe(debug({ title: 'txtfiles:' })),
 gulp.src(['*.bar'], {base: '.'})
 .pipe(debug({ title: 'cssfiles:' }))
)
.pipe(debug({ title: 'merge:' }))
.pipe(zip('myzip.zip'))
```

The strange thing is that I'm getting the .bar files double. And if there are no .bar files I'm not getting any .foo files even when they're there. Something fishy is happening between the vinyl streams and merge. But I have no clue how to drill down further.

Answer (score 0):

It had to do with another component gulp-filter. This caused the streams to bleed into each other. Details:

If you're merging streams like so:

```
merge(
 gulp.src(['*.foo'])
 .filter(myFilter),
 gulp.src(['*.bar'])
 .filter(myFilter)
)
```

Consider revising to this:

```
merge(
 gulp.src(['*.foo']),
 gulp.src(['*.bar'])
)
.filter(myFilter)
```